# #NaN in url issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to add a smooth scroll down functionality to my website so when a user click an anchor tag from another page it links/sends the user to another page and scroll down to a specify div. The code performs correctly however /#NaN appears at the end of the url.

My jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    // run on DOM ready
    // grab target from URL hash (i.e. www.example.com/page-a.html#target-name)

    var target = window.location.hash;

    // only try to scroll to offset if target has been set in location hash

    if (target != '') {
        $('.introsection').hide(0);
        $('#swipe-down').hide(0);
        $('body').css('overflowY', 'scroll');
        $('#home-mobile-nav').css('position', 'fixed');
        $('#home').css('margin-top', '0');
        var $target = jQuery(target);
        jQuery('html, body').stop().animate({
                'scrollTop': $target.offset().top - 150
            }, // set offset value here i.e. 50
            2000,
            'swing',
            function () {
                window.location.hash = target - 40;
            });
    }
});
```

In the console this error appears but I have no idea how to fix this.
[image]

Comment: most likely is your `$target` undefined, aka not found. try and console.log($target) and see if you get the element

Comment: First you need to check that a target exists in the page (`$target.length > 0`). And at the end, where you're getting `#NaN`, notice that you're using `target - 40`, where `target` is supposed to be the ID of your target element (a string!)

Comment: test = `if (target !== ''||target !== undefined)`

Comment: By the way, if #NaN appears at the end of the url, then it's the link before the scrolling page that is problem, as it provides a undefined hashtag